# konvajs - image resize, drag and filter not working at a time

Tags: javascript, canvas, konvajs

In this example I'm using Konvajs 2d canvas library to resize, drag and filter to the image, when I apply the filter the images not resize properly. Can any one help me?

***Note*** : I'm using the google image url, it will show cross orgin domain error. So please try in your local image and try it in firefox browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.4/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Konva Image Resize Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();
        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('Image')[0];
        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();
        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
            case 'topLeft':
                topRight.setY(anchorY);
                bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'topRight':
                topLeft.setY(anchorY);
                bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomRight':
                bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                topRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomLeft':
                bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
        }
        image.position(topLeft.position());
        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if(width && height) {
            image.width(width);
            image.height(height);
        }
    }
    function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();
        var anchor = new Konva.Circle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            stroke: '#666',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: 8,
            name: name,
            draggable: true,
            dragOnTop: false
        });
        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
            update(this);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
            group.setDraggable(false);
            this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
            group.setDraggable(true);
            layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            this.setStrokeWidth(4);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            this.setStrokeWidth(2);
            layer.draw();
        });
        group.add(anchor);
    }
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);
    // darth vader
    var darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
        width: 200,
        height: 137
    });

    var darthVaderGroup = new Konva.Group({
        x: 180,
        y: 50,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
    darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');
    var yodaGroup = new Konva.Group({
        x: 20,
        y: 110,
        draggable: true
    });


    var imageObj1 = new Image();
    imageObj1.onload = function() {
        darthVaderImg.image(imageObj1);
        darthVaderImg.cache();
        darthVaderImg.filters([Konva.Filters.RGBA]);
        darthVaderImg['red'](250);
        darthVaderImg['green'](150);
        darthVaderImg['blue'](150);
        darthVaderImg['alpha'](1);
        layer.batchDraw();    
        layer.draw();
    };
    imageObj1.src = 'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg';
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your filter into a function and called it on image load, and then on drag-move and drag-end.  Am not entirely sure that this is the right way to go for performance - maybe there 'is' a way of caching the image with the filter applied so that the overhead of re-applying the filter is negated.

Note that in the SO snippet you get the cross-domain warning for the filter but the drag-sizing works now, and if you run with a local image the filter stays in effect during the sizing process.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.7.4/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    function update(activeAnchor) {
  
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();
        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('Image')[0];
        var image = darthVaderImg; //group.get('Image')[0];
  
        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();
        // update anchor positions

        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
            case 'topLeft':
                topRight.setY(anchorY);
                bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'topRight':
                topLeft.setY(anchorY);
                bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomRight':
                bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                topRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomLeft':
                bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
        }
        image.position(topLeft.position());
        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if(width && height) {
            image.width(width);
            image.height(height);
        }
    }
    function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();
        var anchor = new Konva.Circle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            stroke: '#666',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: 8,
            name: name,
            draggable: true,
            dragOnTop: false
        });
        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
            update(this);
   applyFilter();
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
            group.setDraggable(false);
            this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
            group.setDraggable(true);
   applyFilter();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            this.setStrokeWidth(4);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            this.setStrokeWidth(2);
            layer.draw();
        });
        group.add(anchor);
    }
 function applyFilter(){
       darthVaderImg.cache();
        darthVaderImg.filters([Konva.Filters.RGBA]);
        darthVaderImg['red'](250);
        darthVaderImg['green'](150);
        darthVaderImg['blue'](150);
        darthVaderImg['alpha'](.1);
        layer.batchDraw();   
  layer.draw();  
 }
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);
    // darth vader
    var darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
        width: 200,
        height: 137
    });

    var darthVaderGroup = new Konva.Group({
        x: 180,
        y: 50,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
    darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');
    var yodaGroup = new Konva.Group({
        x: 20,
        y: 110,
        draggable: true
    });

    var imageObj1 = new Image();
    imageObj1.onload = function() {
        darthVaderImg.image(imageObj1);
      applyFilter();
    };
    imageObj1.src = 'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg';
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```